# How to write addEventListener inside string literals?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, string-literals

I want to create new HTML element using string literals. I added all the parameters I needed using the element as an object and writing parameters to it using setAttribute and methods like this. Now I need to rewrite this code using string literals, where less code and more understandable code.

I was created string literals and throw into them all element except addeventListener:

```
this.parent.innerHTML +=`<${tagName} title="${title} id="${results.id}" href="${title}" onclick=>${title} </a>`;
```

How correctly rewrite addEventListner using string literals?

```
let newElem = document.createElement(tagName);
      newElem.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();
          this.removeElements();
          this.createElem("h3", title);
        }.bind(this),
        false
      );
```

Comment: With string approach you can't have any reference to the element so you can't use `addEventListener`

Answer (score 3):

Because of js scoping behavior, I think finding a solution to do this in-line in your template strings will likely cause you more problems than it's worth. But there's two ways to do this that should play well with your existing code.

But first, fix the errors that will make this not run such as the missing `"` and also using `tagName` to close the html tag as well.

Method 1:

Simply assign the event listener to the parent instead of any of the children. You can use `evt.target` to check if the target is the tag you're expecting, get its properties, etc. Depending on how your code is set up, this might be the optimal solution.

Keep in mind that this event listener should only be added once.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent')
const tagName = 'a'
const title = 'Click Me'
const results = {
  id: 1234567
}

parent.innerHTML += `<${tagName} title="${title}" id="el-${results.id}" href="${title}">${title} </${tagName}>`;

parent.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(evt.target.title)
    // this.removeElements();
    // this.createElem("h3", title);
  })
```

```html
<div class="parent" />
```

Method 2:

Once you assign `innerHTML` the element is added to the document and can be fetched using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). 
You seem to be assigning some id to each tag, so you can just simply use that id to select the tag and then add your event listener.

A class will be better for selecting multiple elements simultaneously.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent')
const tagName = 'a'
const title = 'Click Me'
const results = {
  id: 1234567
}

parent.innerHTML += `<${tagName} title="${title}" id="el-${results.id}" href="${title}">${title} </${tagName}>`;

parent.querySelector(`#el-${results.id}`)
  .addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // this.removeElements();
    // this.createElem("h3", title);
  })
```

```html
<div class='parent' />
```